# Wait Until All Animations Complete Before Removing From DOM with Angular Animation

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-animation

I'm using the staggered feature for Angular animations (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#css-staggering-animations).

Is there a way that I can use this and also have the items not be removed from the DOM until all of the animations are complete?

I created a Plunker showing what I'm talking about: http://plnkr.co/edit/xlVps9v0iINV11CYlUhG

If you click "Add Items" then everything looks fine. If you click "Remove Items" then everything starts collapsing down and the staggered effect turns into an epileptic nightmare.

I suppose by the nature of how the repeat directive works, there might not be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$interval) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.addItems = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      $scope.items.push({ cls: 'class' + (i % 3) });
    }
  };

  $scope.removeItems = function () {
    var k=100;
    $interval(function(){
      $scope.items.splice(k, 1);  
      k--;
    }, 10,100);


  };

});
```

I'd suggest to change the for statement for an Sinterval, it seems like the for statement is too fast for the DOM to render the changes properly.

check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xHdJZ9rpQmOpFFC0ytUk)